# How can i set device memory in selenium python?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-ide

Was doing some tests and comparing them to a real browser vs selenium:
https://bot.sannysoft.com/
One of the atrributes on my webdriver is CHR_MEMORY IS FALSE
On a real browser it is present, anybody has any idea of how I can change that?

```
CHR_MEMORY  FAIL    
{}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify `navigator.deviceMemory` and `navigator.userAgent`

Look at this [example](https://github.com/guzhi-zxy/captchaLearning/blob/851976f8937bc62301d4828a85fa10e57e8c910c/tbCase/taobao/tb_slider.py#L61) based on selenium

Also, here is my approach with Playwright:

```py
import re

from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright

with sync_playwright() as p:
    browser = p.chromium.launch()
    page = browser.new_page()

    page.add_init_script("""
           Object.defineProperty(navigator, 'deviceMemory', {
                 get: () => 8
           });
           Object.defineProperty(navigator, 'userAgent', {
             get: () => 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.169 Safari/537.36'
           });
    """)

    page.goto('https://bot.sannysoft.com')
    html = page.content()

    status = 'failed'
    if match := re.search('CHR_MEMORY<\/td><td class="(.*?)"', html):
        status = match.group(1)

    print(status)
    # Prints 'passed'

    browser.close()
```

Comment: Thank you so much! WIll try this out now, get back to you soon!

Comment: If this will help you, don't forget to mark answer as accepted

Comment: Thanks so much! Worked on my end, + appreciate the example you sent me i am using some of it now! perfect