# Selenium Chrome detection tests

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, chrome-options

I want more sure, than my python selenium chrome will not detected.
So, how i can avoide failed of these tests:

1. https://bot.sannysoft.com/ **CHR_MEMORY  FAIL**
2. https://bot.incolumitas.com/   **"inconsistentWebWorkerNavigatorPropery": "FAIL",
   "inconsistentServiceWorkerNavigatorPropery": "FAIL".**

I read and used any helpfull recommendations like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53039551/selenium-webdriver-modifying-navigator-webdriver-flag-to-prevent-selenium-detec/60405966#60405966),[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71808368/how-can-i-set-device-memory-in-selenium-python) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59367665/spoof-navigator-properties-in-chrome-selenium-webdriver) but yet have no idea, how i can passed tests.

For CHR_MEMORY  FAIL i used this:

```
driver.execute_script("Object.defineProperty(navigator, 'deviceMemory', {get: () => 8})")
```

or

```
driver.execute_cdp_cmd("Page.addScriptToEvaluateOnNewDocument", {
"source": """
                   Object.defineProperty(navigator, 'deviceMemory', {
                     get: () => Number(2)
                   });
                   """
 })
```

But both not work, however **Fp-collect info** points to **"deviceMemory": 8.**
The rest of the tests my code passes successfully.

What mean this params from second tests set? *WebWorkerNavigatorPropery* *ServiceWorkerNavigatorPropery* How can i try to get around them too?

Any help is much appreciated

[sannysoft results IMG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XeHtT.png)

[incolumitas results IMG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TlS2j.png)

Answer (score 0):

The whole problem lies in the user agent. try this sprit that i wrote below. Having registered a memory device and a user agent in one script. I struggled with this for a whole week until I tried this combination and it worked for me.

```
js.executeScript("Object.defineProperty(navigator, 'deviceMemory', {\n" +
                "                 get: () => 8\n" +
                "           });\n" +
                "           Object.defineProperty(navigator, 'userAgent', {\n" +
                "             get: () => 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.169 Safari/537.36'\n" +
                "           });");
```

[image: 1] [image: 2]